# Импорт файлов в bin, операция обратная binwal -e

Tags: linux, прошивка, binwalk

binwalk -e позволяет экспортировать файлы из бинарника.
А есть ли обратная операция позволяющая собрать файлы в аналогичный бинарник?

Comment: Задайте вопрос о конкретной железке и конкретном типе прошивки. Будет проще рассказать о её структуре и как её повторить.

Answer (score 0):

Собирать его придется ручками так как binwalk не запоминает в каком формате и в каком месте что-то лежало. Но он выводит эту информацию при распаковке. А самая сложность будет с форматом и заголовками бинарного файла.

Для перепаковки простых форматов поможет другой проект. https://github.com/rampageX/firmware-mod-kit

Comment: Насколько я понимаю даже если найти нужный адрес и поправить пару бит в самом bin такое не получиться реализовать т.к. там внутри еще хранится хэш сумма, которая не совпадет?

Comment: Вообще у меня внутри bin файла хранится только ядро прошивки. Правильно ли другой проект его пересоберет?

Comment: Контрольные суммы можно пересчитать. Или игнорировать загрузившись с tftp. После ядра ещё обычно лежит диск упакованный в squashfs или подобный архив. Фирмварь мод кит успешно перепаковывает типовые прошивки. Пара байт в бине не внесет изменения в код, а только поломает архив.

Comment: Там архив разбитый на несколько bin файлов и потому в конкретно этой части bin файла лежит только ядро.